# PHP form validation - adding a validation tick box

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm using this tutorial to try and make a form http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml

My form works great but I have included 3 tick boxes that I want the user to tick before they can submit. Creating this validation has had me scratching my head all day!

I've tried making these custom fields but am pretty sure my syntax is wrong. I am well out of my depth here! The tutorial provides example that I tried to implement but the coding is too different for me to use on my form. This is what I tried:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" />
<label for="checkbox" value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('email') ?>'</label><label for='Please tick the box before pressing submit' >
```

And then after the form, inside the script adding:

```
frmvalidator.addValidation("checkbox1","checkbox1","Please tick the box before pressing submit");
```

The form still submits but my validation doesn't happen. If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be really incredible.

I'm not sure if it's the done thing to post the actual page I'm working on as it's my clients website?

Comment: It would be really worth your time ditching the slightly confusing syntax of that black-box validation tool and learning how to do it in raw Javascript. It's really not too hard, and it will be a *lot* more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the documentation.

```
frmvalidator.addValidation("checkbox1","shouldselchk=on");
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to give **value to your checkbox** as below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="1"/>
```

Then, you need to pass **type of validation in second argument** of addValidation function as below

```
frmvalidator.addValidation("checkbox1","shouldselchk=1");
```